# Delta to delta 2000 kVA transformer

Tags: delta

I have a delta to delta 2000 kVA transformer that on power up with no load except whatever is in the main switch gear I am getting 400 volts to ground on one phase 280 on another and 95 on another, the nominal voltage is 480 phase to phase and it is a 3 wire system. The one ground fault light is out until the main gets turned on then it gets better but not completely bright.

Can anyone explain this?

I have had the buss duct and the transformer meggered and they are all good.

Comment: 2 MW! I don't believe you!

Comment: The only thing providing a ground reference on the secondary is the unbalanced parasitic phase to ground capacitance.  Do you have anything intentionally providing ground reference?  e.g. set of VTs with wye-grounded primary and broken delta secondary with loading resistor.

Comment: "*The one ground fault light is out until the main gets turned on then it gets better but not completely bright.*" What is "the main"? (Hit the edit link below your question ...)

Comment: Can you measure Phase to ground capacitance?

Comment: @LeonHeller maybe it is from Alibaba, like this: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/new-siemens-2000-kva-oil-filled_50016026649.html :-)

Comment: it is a 2000 kva. Our plant has 4 of them

Comment: You must have already measure Delta phase inductance right?

Answer (score 0):

Provide an intentional ground reference so neutral point is not determined by parasitic phase-ground capacitance...or find the problem with your existing scheme.

Here is example using wye-grounded primary, broken delta secondary set of VTs and loading resistor:

[image]